# how to using 3 tier architecture using stored procedure and call them flag for implementation in crud?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

how to this procedure implement in 3 layer architecture and using flag like that ?

@eid int=null,
@ename varchar(30)=null,@ecity varchar(20)=null,@eemail varchar(30)=null,@pass nvarchar(20)=null,@flag varchar(20)=null
as
begin
if @flag='i'
begin
insert into emp values(@ename,@ecity,@eemail,@pass)
end

```
if @flag='u'
begin
    update emp set ename=@ename,ecity=@ecity,eemail=@eemail where eid=@eid
end

if @flag='d'
begin
    delete from emp where eid=@eid
end

if @flag='s'
begin
    select * from emp
end

if @flag='l'
begin
    select eid,ename from emp where eemail=@eemail and pass=@pass
end

if @flag='cp'
begin
    update emp set pass=@pass where eemail=@eemail
end
```

Comment: Please read [ask], its not clear what exactly your problem is or how we can help

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), another point where is your stored procedure?, in addition, please add more and correct information to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome @jay, not sure what you mean by 3 layer architecture, can you share a reference? If you clarify your question (you should also do some formatting) I think someone here will be able to answer